# If [ $? -ne 0 ]; not working?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am trying to detect a running service and if not there, try to do something:

```
#!/bin/bash

service --status-all | grep 'My Service' &> /dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Service not there."
else
    echo "Service is there."
fi
```

The service is clearly there but still I am getting "Service not there."

I read about the exit code $? I think maybe the exit code in a series of commands might have effect on what we wanna test?

So I am not sure what went wrong there?

Comment: 0 means success, like what happens when grep finds your pattern. So perhaps your conditional is flipped.

Comment: Perhaps _Service_ is misspelled in `grep 'My Serivice'` (SerIvice)?

Comment: nah, the name is correct, i miss typed it in this question, sorry

Comment: You don't have to redirect output, and it only confuses the issue; instead use `grep -q` to run in "Quiet mode: suppress normal output." (`man grep`) - depending on your grep this could be `-q` and/or `--quiet` and/or `--silent`. This will still set the return status (and can be faster, because it stops grepping as soon as it finds a match)

Comment: The exit code of a pipeline is the exit code of the last command in the pipeline. So your code should work.

Comment: Take out the redirection so you can see if `grep` is really matching anything.

Comment: Run one step at a time. First do `service --status-all` by itself and check its output. Then run `service --status-all | grep 'My Service'` and check _its_ output and exit code... because what you have _should_ work if the output is right. (although there are better ways to do the check)

Comment: Thanks @StephenP your comment above leads to see what's wrong. It's service --status-all. it's returning nothing! Will you please post that as answer?

Comment: You shouldn't check every service's status when you only need to see if your specific service is available. You can run `service servicename status`. The return code will tell the status, `0` is running, `1` is unrecognized service, `3` is stopped. Needless to say, your service script should exit with the correct value depending on its state.

Comment: i was actually deploying an app on an AWS EC2 instance, and before the app is deployed I am using the script above to detect if the service is there, so it looks like service --status-all returns nothing for that matter and after the deployment, service --status-all works. But this seems to be a different problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug what is happening with your test, run one step at a time.

First do `service --status-all` by itself and check its output.  Is the output what you expect it to be, and does it actually include the 'My Service' that you are grepping for?

Then run `service --status-all | grep 'My Service'` and check its output and exit code.  Does it write out the match, and is it's exit code zero `0`?

`man grep` tells us that:

```
The grep utility exits with one of the following values:

 0     One or more lines were selected.
 1     No lines were selected.
 >1    An error occurred.
```

and also

```
-q, --quiet, --silent
         Quiet mode: suppress normal output.  grep will only search a file until a
         match has been found, making searches potentially less expensive.
```

There are also improvements to this process that you can make...

`if` tests the return status of the command list that is executed, and if that status is zero the `then` branch is executed.  Knowing this you can just test the return status of `grep` instead of the return status of `test`.

---

**aside:**
You are using the `[` command, which is also the `test` command (try `man test`)
The `test` command exits with 0 when the test passes (succeeds), or with 1 when the test fails.

```
$ test 7 -eq 7;echo $?
0
$ test 7 -ne 7;echo $?
1
$ [ 7 -eq 2 ];echo $?
1
```

---

With this knowledge, again, you can directly test the exit code of grep.
Suppress grep's output with the "quiet" flag instead of redirection, and use `grep -F` for fixed strings, which is a.k.a. `fgrep`:

```
if ./service --status-all | fgrep -q 'My Servvice'
then
    echo "Service IS there."
else
    echo "Service NOT there."
fi
```

Comment: thanks @StephenP, the steps helps to found out the culprit. For everyone's reference, service --status-works while in the bash prompt, does not seem to return anything during my AWS EC2 deployment. I have to change it to something like if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -q 'My Service' (I used -q now instead of piping to null device as you mentioned), from here: http://www.akamaras.com/linux/linux-script-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-and-start-it-if-its-stopped/